# .zshrc alias for ssh gives "unknown host"

Tags: zsh

New zsher here.

When I do

```
$ ssh user@foo.com
```

all is well. But when I create an alias in .zshrc:

`alias foo='ssh user@foo.com'` and run foo, I get "Could not resolve hostname". Question: how do I begin to figure out what's going on? It all works for me in bash, but that has nothing to do with me knowing what I'm doing!

Update: When I change my alias to `alias foo='user@ip_addess_for_foo'` it works. A bug, maybe.

Comment: What do you mean by "get my internet"?

Comment: Connect to wifi and make sure I can ping host foo.